# How can I use serialization namespace in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

i am unable to find out how can I use serialization namespace in silverlight?

When I use tweetsharp, I find that many methods are missing when I try to use them in my silverlight application.

Can someone show me how can I use those namepace or methods in silverlight?

Comment: There isn't a namespace called "serialization", though there are several with "serialization" as part of their name -- System.Runtime.Serialization, System.Xml.Serialization, System.Runtime.Serialization.Json. Could you update your question to actually tell us which one you're interested in?

Comment: Please, reformat you question and show us what code you have that causes you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight has a much-reduced runtime (to suit the required size, and platform limitations). The WCF core (`DataContractSerializer`) is still available, though:

[System.Runtime.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

as is `XmlSerializer`:

[System.Xml.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e123c76w%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Other 3rd-party serializers are available for Silverlight as libraries.